# How do I use like constraint inside check in mysql?

Tags: mariadb

I want to alter this table right here and check whether the email has '@' or not while inserting the datas.
[image]

I tried this but did not work.
`alter table student add check(student_email like %@%);`

Comment: What version?  `CHECK` was _parsed_ but _ignored_ in older versions.  Works starting with 10.2 (8.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add constraint to check valid email address. try the following.

```
alter table student add constraint student_email check (student_email like '%_@__%.__%')
```

You may need to update `like` according to your needs.